# Using PolicyFileEditor module withtout rebooting the machine

Tags: powershell, group-policy

I want to change my Local Policies by using a powershell script. I use PolicyFileEditor module to so and I am able to change the value of the registry using the Set-PolicyFileEntry command but the changes are not applied to the Local Policies editor unless I restart the machine.

Is there a way to apply the changes without restarting the machine ?

Answer (score 0):

Using gpupdate /force does the trick.